# Update from two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

One is

DF1

```
col1   col2   label
  a      qq       1
  a      ww       1
  a      ee       0
  b      qq       1
  b      ww       0
  b      rr       0
```

Another one is

DF2

```
col1   col2   label
  a      qq
  a      ww
  a      ee
  b      qq
  b      tt
  b      rr
```

So if there is matching pair  with col1 and col2, I want to write label of DF1 to DF2 label.
And if there is no matching pair, I want to just mark 0 to DF2 label.

How can i deal with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
df2['label']=np.where(df2['label'].isna(),df1['label'],df2['label'])
```

Once we print edited `df2` its values will be as follows now.

```
    col1   col2 label
0   a       qq  1.0
1   a       ww  1.0
2   a       ee  0.0
3   b       qq  1.0
4   b       tt  0.0
5   b       rr  0.0
```

Comment: it says operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2435,) (2435,) (8828,)

Comment: @puhuk, not sure but for your given samples it worked fine. I created 2 df from your provided samples and ran above code which executed from me for me.